# Android Google Maps v2 - Grey tiles after zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Ive made an app that uses google maps

When the app is loaded, the map shows up fine in the default zoom level

[image]

But if I zoom, the map doesn't update, it becomes blurry and eventually becomes grey after zooming enough

[image]

The issue only appears on my Galaxy S4 when testing, but if I use a Nexus 7 everything works according to plan. LogCat isnt very helpful either, no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's unlikely to be a problem in your app -- either you get map tiles, or you don't. Does the built-in Maps app behave better on your S4?

Comment: Crappy connection? Sounds like its just not loading.

Comment: yes may be due to connection.

Comment: The maps app works fine, and im on the same wireless with both the S4 and Nexus

Comment: what are the android versions in your s4 and nexus?

Comment: Are the Google Play Services apps on both devices the same versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest clearing the cache for the Google Play Services app.  Its possible some of the map data got corrupted in your cache.

On the Samsung Galaxy S4 it should be under:
`Menu->Settings->Application Manager->Google Play Services`

Then, tap `Clear cache`.